# question about sets and subsets using the definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Assume $A$ and $B$ are two sets such that: $Card(A)=n$ and $Card(B)=m$, also $B⊆A$,Clearly $n\ge 
> m$.
>   define: $$\mathscr{P}(A:B)=\left\{X∈\mathscr{P}(A):B⊆X\right\}$$
>   find the number of elements of $\mathscr{P}(A:B)$

I just know $Card\left(B\right)\le Card\left(X\right)$
how I can answer the question?
does there exist any general formula?

Comment: So, written a different way... given a set $A$ and a set $B$ such that $B\subseteq A$, you ask how many sets $C$ exist such that $B\subseteq C\subseteq A$?  Well... any such $C$ must include every element of $B$.  There are still potentially more elements of $A$ leftover... decide what to do with them, whether you include some, all, or none of those elements and which if so into $C$.

Comment: Absurd. Should not " a " in " P(a)" be replaced by capital " A". Doesn' t this expression  denote the power set of set A?

Comment: yes it's true,it's indeed A

Comment: Absurd. - Have you finally found a proof of the theorem? I've tried to follow Eigen von Eitzen's hint, without success.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try to find a bijection $\mathscr P(A:B)\to \mathscr P(A\setminus B)$.

Comment: HagenvonEitzen.- I've tried to folllow your hint. If I am correct, the relation R from P(A:B) to P (A\B) such that :  Set X is related to Y by R iff   X = B U Y   could  work as a bijection. Is this correct? Unfortunately, I cannot even manage to show that this relation is a function.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $Card(A)=n$ and $Card(B)=m$ then 
$$\mathscr{P}(A:B)=\sum_{k=m}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}{{k}\choose{m}}$$
For example if $A=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$, clearly $Card(A)=3$,and take $Card(B)=2$ then:
$\mathscr{P}(A)=\left\{\left\{\right\},\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left
\{1,3\right\},\left\{2,3\right\},\left\{1,2,3\right\}\right\}$
Since $X∈\mathscr{P}(A)$ and $B⊆X$ we have:
There are ${{3}\choose{2}}$ sets of $\mathscr{P}(A)$ and ${{2}\choose{2}}$ set of $X$ with cardinality 
$2$
There are ${{3}\choose{3}}$ set of $\mathscr{P}(A)$ and ${{3}\choose{2}}$ sets of $X$ with cardinality 
$2$
Summing gives the desired result, also using the formula we have:
$$\mathscr{P}(A:B)=\sum_{k=2}^{3}{{3}\choose{k}}{{k}\choose{2}}$$$$={{3}\choose{2}}{{2}\choose{2}}+
{{3}\choose{3}}{{3}\choose{2}}$$
which is the same as the previous result.

Comment: That sum simplifies to $2^{n-m}\binom{n}{m}$

Comment: It seems like you are counting the ways we can choose $X$ *and* $B$. But $B$ is a fixed set, so only $X$ should vary. For example, if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1\}$, then you want to count the number of subsets of $A$ that has $1$ as an element.

Comment: @ Milten ,I think the cardinality of $B$ is important,for example the power set of $A$ when $A$ has $n$ elements is $2^n$,which is indeed a special case of the given formula (you just need to replace $B$ with empty set) ,and then you will give the result which is $2^n$

Answer (score 0):

Below, a reasoning ( probably not a proof properly speaking) trying to answer the question : in how many ways can one " build" a set X belonging to P(A:B). The number of possible ways to build a member of P(A:B) is the same as the number of members of P(A:B).

[image]

Comment: I've added an answer, look at it.

Comment: there was an error in my answer and I edited that,check it now and tell me if you don't accept that.

Comment: @Absurd. I'd be pleased to check your answer. Unfortunately, though I recognize the symbols you use as pertaining standardly to combinatorics, I cannot understand them, having no knowledge of this field of mathematics.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames I agree with your answer, but there is no reason to consider the two cases separately. The natural thing to do would be to just allow $C$ to be any subset of $A\setminus B$ (empty or not).

Comment: @Milten.- I proceeded in this way in order to explain the construction process of all sets " X" and it seemed to me that it xas clearer to say that the first step consists in using the empty set ( independently of the fact that it belongs to P(A\B). But your're absolutely right, in the end, it would be simpler to say that for all X , X = B U C ( with C being any subset of (A\B) , including the empty set).